# OTRS update CustomerUser table

Tags: mysql, linux, perl, otrs

I'm having trouble updating a `CustomerUser` in OTRS 5.

I'm using command-line Perl scripts and modules.

This is what I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use lib '/opt/otrs/Kernel/System/CustomerUser/DB';

use File::Basename;

use FindBin qw($RealBin);

use lib dirname( $RealBin );
use lib dirname( $RealBin ) . '/Kernel/cpan-lib';
use lib dirname( $RealBin ) . '/Custom';

use Kernel::System::ObjectManager;

local $Kernel::OM = Kernel::System::ObjectManager->new();

my $CustomerUserObject = $Kernel::OM->Get( 'Kernel::System::CustomerUser' );
#
# Searching for customers below works fine
#
#    my $Name = $CustomerUserObject->CustomerName(
#        UserLogin => 'admin',
#    );
#    my @CustomerIDs = $CustomerUserObject->CustomerIDList(
#        SearchTerm  => 'somecustomer',    # optional
#        Valid       => 1,                 # optional
#    );
#    my @CustomerIDs = $CustomerUserObject->CustomerIDs(
#        User => 'some-login',
#    );
#    my %User = $CustomerUserObject->CustomerUserDataGet(
#        User => 'franz',
#    );

# Here is the problem
my $test = $CustomerUserObject->CustomerUserUpdate(
    #Source         => 'CustomerUser',         # CustomerUser source config
    ID             => 'admin',                # current user login
    UserCustomerID => 'acmecompany',
    UserLogin      => 'newuser',              # new user login
    UserFirstname  => 'myfirst',
    UserLastname   => 'mylast',
    UserPassword   => '',                     # not required
    UserEmail      => 'whatever@gmail.com',
    ValidID        => 1,
    UserID         => 4,
);
```

And here is the error that I am receiving:

> DBD::mysql::db do failed: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key  constraint fails (`otrs`.`customer_user`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_customer_user_change_by_id` FOREIGN KEY (`change_by`) REFERENCES
>   `users` (`id`)) at /opt/otrs/Kernel/System/DB.pm line 462. ERROR:
>   ?LogPrefix?-27 Perl: 5.22.1 OS: linux Time: Fri Jan 19 17:29:12 2018
>
> Message: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`otrs`.`customer_user`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_customer_user_change_by_id` FOREIGN KEY (`change_by`) REFERENCES
>   `users` (`id`)), SQL: 'UPDATE customer_user SET  customer_ids = ?,
>   title = ?,  first_name = ?,  last_name = ?,  login = ?,  email = ?,
>   customer_id = ?,  phone = ?,  fax = ?,  mobile = ?,  street = ?,  zip
>   = ?,  city = ?,  country = ?,  comments = ?,  valid_id = ?, change_time = 
>           '2018-01-19 17:29:12'
>       , change_by = ? WHERE LOWER(login) = LOWER(?)'
>
> Traceback (19212):     Module:
>   Kernel::System::CustomerUser::DB::CustomerUserUpdate Line: 961
>   Module: Kernel::System::CustomerUser::CustomerUserUpdate Line: 473
>   Module: update.pl Line: 30

I have read the documentation for
[`Kernel::System::CustomerUser`](http://doc.otrs.com/doc/api/otrs/5.0/Perl/Kernel/System/CustomerUser.pm.html),
with no progress. Some of the documentation even appears to be incorrect.

EDIT: Here is database values:

```
| id | login | email             | customer_id | pw  | title | first_name | last_name | phone | fax  | mobile | street | zip  | city | country | comments | valid_id | create_time         | create_by | change_time         | change_by | customer_ids |


|  4 | admin | whatever@gmail.com | acmecompany | <passwordhash> | Mr.   | myfirst    | mylast  |       |      |        |        |      |      |         |          |        1 | 2018-01-16 11:30:11 |         1 | 2018-01-19 16:50:18 |         2 | 1            |
```

Comment: I suspect that no value is being passed for the `change_by` field - so the DBI module is attempting to insert a `NULL` value in the corresponding column. Hence the foreign key constraint failure.
Out of curiosity, what happens if you add a `ChangeBy` value when invoking the `CustomerUserUpdate()` method - e.g. `ChangeBy => 1`? (The value you pass would have to be the ID of an existing user - otherwise the foreign key constraint would fail again.)
I'm not proposing that as a solution, but it might help debugging.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Thanks for the suggestion, however the error message remains the same when adding the ChangeBy or variations of that. Might have to run to OTRS forum

Comment: Hi. Actually ... Examining the code at https://github.com/OTRS/otrs/blob/rel-5_0_22/Kernel/System/CustomerUser/DB.pm#L960 , it seems that the `UserID` is actually mapped to the `change_by` DB column. Are you sure that the `UserID` you are passing is a valid user ID?

Comment: Made a edit, and yes the UserID is a valid one. I added a "change_by => 2" and same error.

Comment: Are MySQL logs enabled on your server? If so, you could try examining them to see exactly what SQL is being executed (i.e. with  actual values instead of placeholders.)
Alternatively ... If you can edit the source code in your OTRS installation - try adding the line `warn 'Customer update SQL: '.$SQL;` just before the line https://github.com/OTRS/otrs/blob/rel-5_0_22/Kernel/System/CustomerUser/DB.pm#L960 where it executes the query. Then examine the logs to see exactly what the query was?

Comment: Yeah thats a great point. I enabled logging and its weird... I copied the query directly, as it appeared in the logs, and placed it in the sql prompt and it accepted it.

Comment: I think I'll just write my own function to updates values instead of using theirs

Comment: Hi. The only explanation I can fathom is that OTRS is configured to use a different database than the one you are connecting to via the SQL prompt (although with the same schema). Am intrigued as to what other causes might be.

Comment: Ill place a question on the forum and get back to you. Thanks for the help debugging